# How I can hide SKU from product page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Can anybody please tell me how I can hide the SKU from the product page in Magento 2?

Answer (score 19):

Create your own layout file for the product page:

```
 app\design\frontend\VENDOR\THEME\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml
```

Then, paste this code in the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

This way, you can remove the SKU block without copying the whole file. Using the Layout `remove` attribute is also best practice!

Answer (score 7):

The solution from MagentoOdoo.com won’t work since you can’t remove system attributes. Also if it did work, it would remove the attribute completely, and not just from the view.

To remove it just from the view, copy the following file:

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml
```

to your template folder, which should be something like this:

```
 app\design\frontend\**your_theme**\theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml
```

Then remove the following block of code (should be somewhere around line 36)

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
  </arguments>
</block>
```

And replace it with:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true"/>
```

clear the cache, and the SKU should be removed from the product view.

Comment: Ik heb precies gedaan hoe je hebt beschreven, maar SKU staat er nog steeds.

Las dat dit ook een algemeen bekend probleem is, zie https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-Feature-Requests-and/Magento-2-has-no-ability-to-hide-the-SKU-from-a-frontend-product/idi-p/46499

Werkt het bij jou wel?

Hoor graag van je,

Kevin van der Toorn

Comment: Did you clear caches and reindex? Also check if the path where you copied the file to is correct. You can temporarily update the core file to see if that works.

Comment: I made an exact copy of my theme (only editing the theme name in all files that contain the name), applied the new theme and it works. I have no idea why. Thanks for your answer and reply.

Comment: @kevin In plaats van dat je de code van het originele bestand kopieert naar je eigen bestand, probeer deze zin: <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true" />

Answer (score 0):

In your module create a layout named catalog_product_view.xml (No need for controller)

{venor_name}/{module_name}/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Put this code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true" />

    </body>
</page>
```

Flush the cache

```
Php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope it helps you.