# How to remove SKU on the product page in magento2

Tags: magento2, product

I want to remove the SKU from the product display page using XML .

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the solution by xml layout to remove.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/106966/57751

Or use event to remove : `layout_load_before`

Check action : `$observer->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view'`

Then remove : `$observer->getLayout()->unsetElement('product.info.sku')`